# How to make SQLi vulnerable login in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been given the task to make a vulnerable php application and this is my code for  a login page. The problem is that I cannot make it vulnerable. When I attempt to use the login field for SQL injection nothing happens.

How can I make it vulnerable to a SQLi attack, `or '1'='1'` or similar?

checklogin.php

```
require "config.php";
$tbl_name="members"; 

mysql_connect("$servername", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword")or die("Spajanje bezuspješno");
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("Selektrianje baze bezuspješno");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
  $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
  $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
  header("location:addnews.php");
}
else {
  header("location:login_failed.php"); 
}
```

config.php

```
$servername='localhost';    
$dbusername='root';                
$dbpassword='qwe123';               
$dbname='ferida';     

connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword)
{
  global $link;
  $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbusername","$dbpassword");
  if(!$link){die("Ne mogu se spojiti na MySQL");}
  mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("Ne mogu otvoriti bazu podataka".mysql_error());
}
```

database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4*/ ;

INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'P@ssw0rd'),
(2, 'r00t', '1qa2ws'),
(3, 'editor', 'q1w2e3r4');
```

Comment: This sure appears to be a "Do my homework for me" problem which is largely frowned upon.

Comment: first turn off `magic_quotes_gpc`

Comment: It's hilarious how people in 2000-2012 (around) made this kind mistake all the time, while people in 2018 can't even do it on purpose

Answer (score 4):

It is actually vulnerable to SQL injection. I suspect the problem might be with the values you're entering for the username and password.

You need to make sure that the SQL statement created by the SQL injection code is valid and returns *exactly one row* to satisfy the `$count==1` check.

One way to do this is enter the username as `admin'#`. This closes off the username string and starts a comment, which causes whatever password you enter to be ignored. So you can log in without supplying a password.

Using `1=1` type injections won't work as well since they typically return all rows in the database, failing the `$count==1` check. A variant which would work is to have a username of `admin` and a password of `1' or username='admin`.

Answer (score 1):

as dan said - you already are. in the username put root and in the password put `'or '1'='1`

this transforms the sql statement from

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='root' and password='' or '1' = '1'
```

notice you have to complete the quotes placed around the password. You can also use an sql comment `--` or `#` to ignore any later commands

a good tool to learn about these things is [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)

Comment: This example definitely constitutes SQL injection. Note, though, the statement returns _all_ rows from the members table. To login with @Morena's code we need to return exactly one row. To make it work, you could set the password to `' or '1'='1' limit 1 #` to make sure only one row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using another server for testing than the code will later be run on? Check the settings. Is `magic_quotes_gpc` turned on or your server but not on the other (if you have PHP < 5.4.0)?